# Update mongo dates masive in string format

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a 2000 Millions documents.
I want to update a field that is a String representing a Date in this format --> "timestamp" : "2019/10/03 05:24:45.000"
I want to add 30 days to each row that matches a certain condition.

I accomplished yet, but the perfomance is very poor and I think there is a better way to do it.

Example document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d962843525def14360ca35b"), 
    "sensor" : "sensor_87.202:h", 
    "timestamp" : "2019/10/03 05:24:45.000", 
    "value" : 5.0, 
    "samplingFrequency" : NumberLong(15)
}
```

This is the way I did it:

```
var bulk = db.Measure.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
count = 0;
db.getCollection('Measure').aggregate([
    {$match:{sensor:'sensor_88.11:h',timestamp : {'$gt': '2019/09/02 11:40:00.000', '$lt': '2019/10/02 11:41:00.000'}}},
    {$project:{sensor:1,timestamp:  {$dateToString: { format: '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%L', date: {$add: [{$dateFromString: { dateString: '$timestamp'}},1000 * 3600 * 24 * 30]} } }}}
])
.forEach(function(x){ 
    bulk.find({'_id':x._id}).updateOne({$set:{'timestamp':x.timestamp}});
    count++;
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.Measure.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});
print(count);    
if ( count % 1000 !=0 ){
    bulk.execute();
}
```

The match and project stages returns around 76k documents that has to be updated in the forEach.
¿Is there a way to do it for all the documents matched without a loop?

One note, if I replace the content of the function with a simple print("test"); the perfomance is very good. So I think that the problem is on the update.

Comment: You can try out updating the data in batches, check out this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/

Comment: Ok, thx. I tried with a better performance but in my opinion not enough. I am going to update the question.

Comment: `print()` and a complex operation that involves parsing a string, convert it into date, and manipulate it, then update the document are two _very_ different operations. You _cannot_ compare the performance of the two. Since the operation is complex, the only way to speed this up is to get a larger machine.